# Wildfly stuck at starting mode

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly

Recently I've got a strange Wildfly bug where I can't start my server properly.
When I start the server empty I've got:

```
 [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full
 14.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 6.0.1.Final) started in 3430ms - Started 306 of 527 
 services (321 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Which is pretty standard but even tho it says `started in 3430ms` when I go on my servers tab the server says `[Starting, Synchronized]` and the only option I have is to terminate it rather than restarting it. It also don't update my `WEB` content directly and I have to restart the server every single time when I make a slight change which is extremely time-consuming. I've tried so far:

deleted .eclipse, deleted eclipse-workplace, install new eclipse ide, install new `JBoss tool (4.9 final)`, using `new/different` Wildfly.
And none of these solved the problem.

Comment: have you checked the server.log? is there any error in the log? if so can you post

Comment: @Shubham that's the thing. There is no errors everything looks fine in the logs but when I go to the server tab it says 'Starting' not Started like the logs. What it may be?

Comment: from where i understand its not a JBoss issue but some compatibility issue, did you try installing the same JBoss on some other machine?

Comment: @Shubham Yes it works perfectly fine on other machines. It also worked fine on mine until a few days ago.

Comment: well you have the answer to the problem i guess

Comment: @Shubham I think there is a problem because even tho it says started in the log after the timeout of 400 secs the server terminate itself.

Comment: can you try changing the port , i think you have installed something which is blocking your port and wildfly is unable to access that port which is why its still trying to connect and still waiting and connection times out or can you check the firewall?

Comment: @Shubham I've also tried this. Tried on 8080,8081,8082,8088.. Also added offsets and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue with a newly configured WildFly 24+ in Eclipse 2023-12 (4.30.0) using JBoss Tools 4.29.0.Final.

Working solution for me:

1. Open Server configuration
2. Navigate to 'Server State Detectors'
3. Change "Startup Poller" from "Web Port" to "Management Service"

Answer (score 0):

> the only option I have is to terminate it rather than restarting it

This feature was removed from Jboss Tools at version 4.5 when the direct toolbar buttons were removed. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-24528
You can try to downgrade Jboss Tools

> It also don't update my WEB content directly and I have to restart the
>   server every single time when I make a slight change

Check you have added the resources on the server. Right click on server -> Add and remove...
Once a resource is added wildfly should update automatically your changes, also you can right click on the resource and do a manual incremental or full publish.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have the latest JBoss tool 4.9 Final. I think it's not about that.

Comment: Thats what I'm saying... The restart option was removen in v4.5.

Comment: I have a JEE project. EJB and WEB module which I pack in EAR file and deploy. I don't to restart the server and log in, in my web app every time I make a change looks like my wildfly is no longer updating the changes instantly. How can I change this?

Comment: Also I think there is a problem because even tho it says started in the log after the timeout of 400 secs the server terminate itself.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing "Port Offset" it works. Instead of offset 0 the field had the port number 8080. I had to recreate the server configuration in the server view (New / Server).

[image]

Comment: Was the port offset 8080 a default setting or was that something which was manually input by accident?

Comment: I'm sure I did not type 8080 so it is either a default from JBossTools or was parsed from the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I Recently got the same issue and mine got solved with the steps.give a try

1.Double Click on the configured Wildfly server

2.Go to Server Behhaviour section >

3.Disable this checkbox "Server Lifecycle is externally managed."